# Vectorize: Limit the increase in value between two subsequent numbers in Series (or list/array/whatever)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I need to apply a recursive rule to my data: the increase in value between two subsequent numbers cannot be more than 0.5.

If the increase between the value in row n (`x[n]`),  and the value in row n+1 (`x[n+1]`) is greater than this cap, the value in row n+1 should be replaced by `x[n+1] = x[n] + 0.5`

The new value of `x[n+1]` should then be used to see if the subsequent `x[n+2]` value is within the cap.

I know that I could do this in a loop, but I'm searching for a vectorized way to do it. Wondering if I could use something like [scipy's lfiltic](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfiltic.html), but I haven't seen a similar example.

Sample data:

```
pd.Series(np.random.randn(10,))

0    0.016366  
1   -1.180037  
2    0.967760  
3    0.337723  
4   -0.230030  
5   -0.276347  
6   -1.872155  
7   -1.242532  
8    2.315929  
9   -1.723003
```

Sample output:

```
0    0.016366  
1   -1.180037  
2   -0.180037  # <- new value because of cap
3    0.337723  
4   -0.230030  
5   -0.276347  
6   -1.872155  
7   -1.242532  
8   -0.242532  # <- new value because of cap 
9   -1.723003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution which requires only `O(log(N))` parallel passes over the data at the expense of requiring `O(N*log(N))` total operations (where a parallel pass might involve an aggregation over an large contiguous range of elements to a single value).

Whether this counts as a vectorized solution depends on what primitives you have available and how much work you want to put into rephrasing a divide-and-conquer algorithm as a vectorized algorithm, which is (at least in this case) possible, but a tends to be a lot of work.

In the base case, you have a single-element vector and you're done.

Otherwise divide your data in half and recursively apply the rule to each half. Let's call the resulting vectors `a` and `b`.

Let `c = [a[-1] + 0.5,a[-1] + 1.0,..]` (where `a[-1]` is the last element in `a`)

Find the first element in `b` which is < the corresponding element in `c`.

`i = indexFirstTrue(b < c)` # (returns `len(b)` if all of them are greater).

Then splice in the appropriate part of `c`:

`return a + c[:i] + b[i:]`

Here it is as a Python function on lists (which of course defeats the whole purpose, but it gives the right idea):

```
import itertools


def restrict(x):
    l = len(x)
    if l == 1:
        return x
    a = restrict(x[:l//2])
    b = restrict(x[l//2:])
    c = list(itertools.islice(itertools.count(a[-1]+0.5, 0.5), len(b)))
    try:
        i = [x < y for (x, y) in zip(b, c)].index(True)
    except ValueError:
        i = len(b)
    return a + c[:i] + b[i:]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the first element shall always be seleceted. Use [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) to find the difference between adjacent elements and [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to chose either `x[n]` or `x[n-1]` depending on the difference.

Example (modifying input):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.randint(100, size=10)
cap = 33

d = np.diff(x)
x_n = x[1:]
x_n_minus_one = x[:-1]

print(x)
x[1:] = np.select([d > cap, d <= cap], [x_n_minus_one, x_n])
print(x)

# [51 92 14 71 60 20 82 86 74 74]
# [51 51 14 14 60 20 20 86 74 74]
```

Alternatively, use [`np.choose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) and abuse the fact that `false`/`true` evaluate to `0`/`1`:

```
x[1:] = np.choose(d > cap, [x_n, x_n_minus_one])
```

Comment: This is helpful, but doesn't catch the effects that updating one value limited by the cap has on the next value. For example, once you cap the 20 to 82 jump, so that 82 becomes 20, the following jump from 20 to 86 should also have the cap applied to it.

Comment: Doh. For some reason I though you explicitly wanted it the other way round :) This certainly makes the problem more difficult. I'm not even sure if this is efficiently vectorizable. If you have a JIT compiler available ([numba](https://numba.pydata.org/)) the easiest approach would be probably to put the loop in a jitted function.